# Open only specific input field created with ngFor loop in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

table.component.html:

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

        <td>
          <div *ngIf='!openDateSold; else dateEdit2'>
            {{ item.dateSold | date:'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}
            <br>
            <button class="icon-button" type="button" (click)='showDateSold()'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" style="font-size:15px"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <ng-template #dateEdit2>
            <input id="date" #date type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="item.dateSold | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="item.dateSold=$event">
            <button type="button" (click)='showDateSold()'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></i>
            </button>
          </ng-template>
        </td>
</tr>
...
```

table.component.ts:

```
...
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  public openDateSold: boolean;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.openDateSold = false;
  }
  showDateNotified() {
    this.openDateNotified = !this.openDateNotified;
  }
  ...
}
```

The third `<td>` creates a column that looks like this:
[image: Image of third column]

I should be able to click the pencil icon and edit that specific date. However, when I click it, it opens the input field for all the dates. Here's an image where you can see what I mean:
[image: Image of third column after clicking icon]

How can I make it so that when I click an icon, it only shows the input field in that specific cell?

Comment: When you click the button, you're toggling what appears to be some sort of component-level boolean or flag. How do you expect it to know which particular item in your list of data it should be targetting?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component and use its scope:

main component

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

  <item item="item"></item>
</tr>
</table>
```

ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './item.component.css' ]
})
export class ItemComponent  {
  openDateSold;
  openDateNotified:any;
  @Input() item:any
ngOnInit() {
    this.openDateSold = false;
  }
  showDateSold() {
    this.openDateSold = !this.openDateSold;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<td>
    <div *ngIf='!openDateSold; else dateEdit2'>
        {{ item.dateSold | date:'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}
        <br>
        <button class="icon-button" type="button" (click)='showDateSold()'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" style="font-size:15px"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #dateEdit2>
        <input id="date" #date type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="item.dateSold | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="item.dateSold=$event">
        <button type="button" (click)='showDateSold()'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></i>
            </button>
    </ng-template>
</td>
```

[demo:stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-only-specific-input-field-created-with-ngfor-loop-d-nbts7d?file=src%2Fitem%2Fitem.component.html)

if you want only one item to be open you should try [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-only-specific-input-field-created-with-ngfor-loop-d-qhxvrj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Define this varibale in TS

```
toggle=[]

<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

        <td>
          <div *ngIf='!openDateSold; else dateEdit2'>
            {{ item.dateSold | date:'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}
            <br>
            <button class="icon-button" type="button" (click)='showDateSold();toggle[i]=!toggle[i]'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" style="font-size:15px"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <ng-template #dateEdit2>
            <input id="date" #date type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="item.dateSold | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="item.dateSold=$event">
            <button type="button" (click)='showDateSold();toggle[i]=!toggle[i]'>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></i>
            </button>
          </ng-template>
        </td>
</tr>
```

...

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. Could you be more specific about how to define the variable in the ts component and how to use it there?

Comment: Your example works on that website, but when I try it in my code I keep getting `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, because I guess toggle[0] was never defined.

Comment: did you add *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"  this in your code

Comment: Yeah, I had that line in my original code. The problem occurs when it goes to the line with this: `*ngIf="toggle[i]"`, because that value was never initialized. Same thing happens when I click the icon, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-only-specific-input-field-created-with-ngfor-loop-din-angu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

> Component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

    <td>
        <div *ngIf='!item.isEdit'>
            {{ item.dateSold | date:'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}
            <br>
            <button class="icon-button" type="button" (click)='showDateNotified(item)'>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" style="font-size:15px"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf='item.isEdit'>
            <input id="date" #date type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="item.dateSold | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="item.dateSold=$event">
            <button type="button" (click)='showDateNotified(item)'>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> Component.ts

```
showDateNotified(items:any) {
    items.isEdit = !items.isEdit;
}
```

Comment: This works. However, by doing this, I'm adding another parameter to the item object (i.e. isEdit), and that breaks the rest of my code (I'm sending this object to a REST service and the service doesn't recognize isEdit, so it returns an error). Any other way to do it without adding another property to the object?